Questions on Panpsychism; Locality and Boundary
I recently watched an interview with Philip Goff, who holds panpsychism to be true; that is, he believes consciousness or experience occurs in objects other than living animals and is much more fundamental to our reality. And I have some questions regarding what panpsychism is claiming and have a few examples I would like clarification on.
Philip began by claiming that sub-atomic particles like electrons have an extremely rudimentary form of experience. I can understand the sentiment he is describing; most likely the electron will not feel pain or have complex thoughts like humans, because our sensory feelings and thoughts are directly correlated to physical changes in the system of our brain. But perhaps the electron, in following the rules of the physical world, has some sort of qualitative experience.
My question is less on the argument for panpsychism being true but more what the theory claims about these specific cases revolving around locality and boundary.
It is hard to describe where consciousness exists or even what that means, but one can conceptualize some sense of locality when thinking of consciousness. For instance, we can directly correlate experiences of humans to changes in their brain. And we can also change aspects of the brain and induce certain experiences. So perhaps in panpsychism, we can generalize locality of consciousness to different physical objects and systems: consciousness is localized to a system exactly and only when changes in that system affect the experience. Is this an accurate description of locality in panpsychism?
Furthermore, it appears that more complex forms of consciousness (like animals) may be localized in more complex systems. Is it correct to interpret that panpsychism claims there is a correlation in the complexity of systems and experiences? Philip Goff makes this implication by detailing the hierarchy of complex systems from humans to animals to bugs down to fundamental particles (or really excitations in fields) and stating there are different qualities of experiences in each system.
My brain is extremely complex and it appears that my experience is localized within that system (using the definition above). But half my brain is also extremely complex. For that matter, any contiguous chunk of my brain is extremely complex. Does panpsychism imply that there are many independent conscious experiences localized within my brain? (I use the word independent because I only experience one experience. There may be other experiences; the electron bouncing around my brain follows the same laws of physics and experiences the same rudimentary experience regardless of being in my head. And thus molecules also must experience the same experience regardless of being inside or outside of my head. But I, the conscious being that feels it is controlling my hands to write this sentence, cannot access them. Perhaps there are other contiguous chunks of my brain that also believe they are writing this sentence.)
If there are millions of independent conscious experiences in my brain, why is there only one that has the experience of driving my body? This experience can perceive the outside world with the full extent of its body's senses, it feels it can make choices about its body's behavior, and most importantly, the experience feels atomic.
Furthermore, my single unitary conscious experience is not correlated with a definite structure of my brain. That is, I can somewhat "Ship of Theseus" my brain (in a loose analogy). If you were to take my brain and modify its structure by instantly changing the location and connection of 20 neurons, I conjecture that my conscious experience would continue to remain unitary, consistent and very similar to the old state. One can also remove those neurons, and I conjecture that I would retain the same quality of experience as well as its consistency. This demonstrates that we can make modifications to the system of the brain (up to some threshold) without affecting the quality of the experience in a major way.
Let's expand on this thought experiment. Call the system of your entire body System A. Now consider the system that is composed of your entire body and brain accept for your visual cortex. Call it System B. (I am not imagining a possible world where your brain is missing the visual cortex, I am referencing the world where your brain is complete and am only considering the specified chunk of your brain and excluding the rest, just as exclude the air outside your head). Panpsychism would claim that this system has a conscious experience. Question, would this system's experience be almost identical to a human except it cannot qualitatively experience light?
One could say that the experience of System B may be completely and radically different to that of a human. You may never be able to conceive of it, similar to trying to understand the experience of an electron. But it appears that the correlation of experience and system structure is continuous. That is, small changes in the system induces small changes in the experience (see Ship of Theseus analogy). And we know experimentally that a person who damaged their visual cortex will have the experience of a human being. Furthermore, brains without a functioning visual cortex do not have the ability to qualitatively experience light. So one could imagine that the experience of System B is just like yours but without the ability qualitatively experience light. If that is not the case, keep adding neurons back to System B until the experience is just like yours but without vision. This consciousness even has the same linguistic thoughts that you are having because they are located in different parts of the brain which it has full access to.
You cannot say that the experience of System B is the one driving your body. This is because any human with a functioning visual cortex, including my own body, seem to behave, speak, and navigate as if they can interpret light. Furthermore, System B may even think that it can interpret light because the rest of the brain in that system is behaving as if it can. So did we just create a system that experiences beliefs based off of visual experience without actually experiencing visuals? Are there many "incomplete" experiences in your brain that are almost identical to you? How do you know that you are the most "complete"? Why don't those other experiences feel they make decisions for your body?
A response. Consider System B, there is a large set of neurons on the boundary of this system connected to neurons outside the system. You can think of these neurons like buses going from the CPU to memory in a computer; we treat them as separate systems, but they are constantly communicating. The neurons in System B are constantly communicating to neurons outside in the visual cortex, so perhaps the experience does have the capacity to interpret light in some way. But it seems like at this point we are just collapsing all conscious experiences localized in the brain to the same experience. But if you accept that, it seems like it leads to absurdity. Can't you just continue that operation and collapse every experience into one? Where does qualitative experience draw its boundary? Why do two different humans have two separate subjective experiences?

Part of what you asking is called the combination problem for panpsychism:"This is very difficult to make sense of: “little” conscious subjects of experience with their micro-experiences coming together to form a “big” conscious subject with its own experiences... The general consensus among panpsychists is that there is currently no wholly adequate solution to the combination problem." Panpsychists believe that a solution will eventually be found just as physicalists believe the same for the hard problem of consciousness.

@Conifold The SEP article assumes causal closure of the physical as a starting point for panpsychism.  If the physical is causally closed to combination or not on the mental side, then there is no way to test combinatorial hypotheses, and therefore no method by which "a solution will eventually be found".  Panpsychism faces the same testability problem that epiphenomenalism has.  Under epiphenomenalism, the experience of consciousness has no effect on what one says about that experience.  Panpsychism has the same problem.  Unless causal closure is abandoned, and then it turns into dualism.

@Dcleve SEP traces the combination problem to James who never heard of the causal closure. And the task of explaining hypothetically how "shuffling and packing" consciousnesses can produce a collective one is orthogonal to both that and testability. Panpsychism is a species of either idealism or property dualism anyway, so that is not the issue either. It needs some metaphysical account of combination, or a promise of one, at least, to get past the incredulous stare.

Is there a unit of consciousness that is attributed to atom. The behaviour of an atom cannot be determined by science but consciousness has a reason behind its behaviour if we cannot determine the behaviour of an atom is there a will behind it?

I get the impression that panpsychism is very much a work in progress. Like Goff, I think that there is a hierarchy of consciousness. Fundamental particles have some form of awareness. Simpler organisms have awareness, but more complex organisms have sentience. Higher organisms are self-conscious. The awareness at the fundamental level may feed into universal consciousness. At the moment, there is no means of putting all of these possibilities together into a coherent understanding. But any such world view would have to move beyond the purely mathematical, physicalist view that is currently dominant. Essentially, the fundamental stuff is matter/consciousness. In my view, quantum physics points us in that direction.

Panpsychism has always sounded rather "new age" to me. I never "got past the incredulous stare", as @Conifold put it. I guess my fundamental problem with it relates to a difference in behavior between living and inanimated things, which to me is evident, but that panpsychists seems to forget or ignore.
I see that as disrespectful towards life, its specificity and "special status" as compared to "death." Its dignity if you wish.
In his answer, @causative states that "The goal is the "hub" that unifies and draws together the information into a coherent picture." I agree with that teleological approach. And I ask: What is the goal of an atom? What is the goal of a chair?
Attributing teleology to non-living things is a category error.
Consequently, to me experience is, essentially, something for the living, of no use to the dead. Living creatures do not behave at all like dead things. They eat and excrete, they reproduce, they fight or flee. A chair does not flee or fight, like cats do. As a result, a chair is notoriously easier to sit on than a cat. That is in my view an important distinction. And it explains why cats have a need for some sort of mind, while chairs don't. A chair wouldn't know what to do with a mind because it doesn't act autonomously like an animal does. And thus it does not need to make choices.
It also explains why the mind does not come free of cost for the animal. It necessitates a specific, specialized organ, and is therefore correlated spatially with a living, ultra-complex "brain", which sucks up much energy to produce said "mind". Chairs don't have brains, and so they can't have minds.

Just as a point of argument, a conscious choice and behaviour  either came from inanimate objects or God?

@8Mad0Manc8 Your question, to me, is synonymous with: Where does life (and hence teleonomy) come from? Did it emerge naturally, by itself, from inanimate matter or did it require some additional, already teleonomic force (God) to happen? I vote for the former. My answer is thus: It came by luck. Another way to say the same thing is: life (and hence teleonomy) was possible, and therefore it happened, given enough time. But that doesn't mean there is no difference between the background and the phenomena that emerges from it.


If there are millions of independent conscious experiences in my brain, why is there only one that has the experience of driving my body?

Because there's one system (distributed through the brain) that coherently optimizes for your goals. Consciousness follows function. "Your brain minus your visual cortex" is not an effective optimizer for your goals. That's why "your brain minus your visual cortex" is not the consciousness that experiences driving your body.
A conscious system is a system that is seeking some goal. In order to seek the goal, the system first draws together information. The system then takes an action compatible with optimization of the goal, given the available information. The information - as it functionally relates to the goal - is what the system is consciously aware of. The goal is the "hub" that unifies and draws together the information into a coherent picture.
You may object that goals are teleological, not physical. But optimization is physical; a system may tend over time towards some stable equilibrium that happens to optimize some function. We call this an attractor of the system. A goal is an attractor of the system.
Many systems have attractors, even simple systems. That's where the panpsychism comes in; even simple systems can draw on information to optimize for an attractor, and by that standard they are conscious.

That model seems selective and inconsistent. Does that assume that consciousness and experience can merge together to form one? Do the electrons in my brain stop experiencing their rudimentary consciousness? If they do stop and experiencing and form into one, doesn't that imply that the consciousness is not emergent but actually indicate something separately physical? That is, sometimes an electron "feels" but if it is part of a bigger conscious being, its feeling merges with the surroundings--the consciousness migrates.

Also I don't understand what you mean with goal. Do you mean that a goal is any physical outcome that follows from the laws of physics? Because the electrons are not following a goal regarding "intention" but they are obeying the laws of nature. But then what is the distinction of what is a goal and what is just random physics pushing stuff around?

@BENG No, the electrons have a limited consciousness regardless of what they're part of. To be clear, "your brain minus your visual cortex" does have a sort of consciousness; it's just not the consciousness in control of your body, because if you remove the visual cortex you are not left with a good optimizer for your goals (said goals involving how you move your body).

The concept of optimization and goals are a result our human trait to categorize things into classes and outcomes.

Whether a system has an attractor is an objective physical property of the system. Electrons do have attractors; they tend to move towards positive charges and away from negative ones, for example.

what about my brain with 20 neurons missing? That has exactly the same "goal" as before. and that system does exist in parallel with my whole brain

It's really the goal that matters, not the number of neurons. Supposing that your brain with 20 neurons missing has exactly the same goal as before - and supposing it has access to the same information that it uses to optimize for that goal - then it would have the same experiences. But really if you take away 20 neurons you do remove some information. So it wouldn't have exactly the same consciousness.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
